# After rename file name site went down - Java

Tags: java, jboss

I am working on some server files in jboss. The main file of data `jboss/standalone/deployments/data.tar and data.war` I just renamed to data1.tar and data1.war and come back site went down. Again I renamed with data.tar still not working. I am unable to to figure out.

How to fix this am not java programmer, could some one help me

Comment: `tar` or `jar` ?

Comment: The folder have two files one is .tar and one its .war

Comment: You usually don't play with the tar files..there is now a conflict between the two..you need to see the usages of the file and restart the server

Comment: so you have probably just autodeployed a new app called `data1` which is going to confict with `data`

Comment: did you restart your server?

Comment: @MichaelMeyer no, it will fix?

Comment: 'fess up and get the java support people involved

Comment: @ScaryWombat how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You renamed the application - what did you expect exactly? The server took that as (a) uninstallation of the application under the old filename and (b) installation of an application under the new filename.

Don't fiddle around with things like this.

Comment: Sorry, But how to fix this.

Comment: Rename it back, of course, and stop fiddling around with running software, or, if I may say so, with things you don't understand.

Comment: Thank you. I renamed it back. But site not working any other solution?

Comment: Restart the application server, you've hosed it.